# maven how to include /src/main/resources

Tags: maven, resources

I have a mavenized project with jar packaging, have standard layout:

```
/src/main/java
/src/main/resources
```

When I execute: `mvn package`

I am expecting the resulting jar (non-executing) file to include the resources folder and everything inside that folder from the project(i.e. some xml files), but when I open the 
jar file I only see the com folder where and the contents of the resources folder in the top level...

I think the above is default for maven3, but I want to include the `resources` folder in the jar file...

Comment: please show your pom.xml, especially the `build` section

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will not see `src/main/resources` in resulted jar file.

You will only see the contents of `src/main/resources` in the jar file.

So, if you did not create a package structure for your resource files and dumped everything into `src/main/resources` directory, you will see your resource files at the top level of your jar.

If you want your resources appear under certain directory in the resulting jar file, create such a directory under `src/main/resources` tree.

Comment: but how can I do that? do i create folders, packages, ...? and then, i can't copy my properties file in that structure!?

Comment: @Pete. Yes, you create folders under `src/main/resources`.  And remember that in Java a package is just a fancy alias for directory tree.  So if you package name is `org.mycompany.mypackage`, and you need `myproperteis.properties` in there, then the path to that file should be `src/main/resources/org/mycompany/mypackage/myproperties.properties`